# Para que serve o [QSA] e semelhantes na RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex

Tenho como exemplo o seguinte `RewriteRule ^(Home)?/?$ page/php/Home.php [NC,L]`
Sei que o `NC` é `Non-Case(Não diferencia maiúsculas e minusculas)`.
`L` quer dizer que se um `RewriteRule` for verdadeira ele para de verificar.

Mas vi diversos exemplos usando QSA também e não encontrei uma explicação que me esclarecesse o que significa o QSA e qual seu uso.
Então pegunto, O que significa esse QSA? Qual seu uso? Existem outros "operadores"(não sei como são denominados) alem desses? se sim, quais suas utilidades?

Answer (score 6):

Esses "operadores" são chamados 'flags' do `mod_rewrite` do apache

Aqui tem uma lista delas (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

[QSA] significa Query String Append.

Mantem a mesma query string e adiciona `var=val` no fim da URI

```
RewriteRule ^/pagina /pagina?var=val [QSA]
```

A URI: `/site5/ver.php?pagina=1` vai ser reescrita para `/site/ver.php?site=5&pagina=1`

```
RewriteRule /site5(.*) /site/$1?site=5 [QSA]
```

Comment: Muito bom o link, não havia encontrado ele antes, sugiro que adicione algumas das flags mais importantes a sua resposta para deixa-la mais completa

Answer (score -3):

Apesar de o [mdma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15079/mdma) ter respondido muito bem. Gostaria de acrescentar que é muito utilizado em frameworks principalmente em PHP para evitar a perda da Query String e mesmo assim conseguir continuar trabalhando com urls amigáveis.
Vale dar uma lida no link informado.